# Adding Object components from JcomboBox to text area

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Hello I have a JComboBox with objects inside. this objects are person objects witch contain name, idnr etc. and every object is shown in this JComboBox.

When I select one of the objects I want the several properties of this object to be shown in a textarea next to it.

What I do now is

```
overzicht = textarea
personenList is the JcomboBox

if(event.getSource() == personenList) {
     overzicht.append();
}
```

But how can I append every component I want in the area like this? ( assuming I am doing it right until now )

P.S not every component is a String!

Comment: Im not sure what are you calling `component` . You mean `Person` properties?

Comment: What do you mean ?  **I want the several components of this object to be shown**. You mean if you select **name** from `jComboBox` you want to display all details of person associated with this name on `jTextArea`?

Comment: Yes. I mean the properties. When I choose person A i want his name, bank account number etc to be shown. and when choosing person B I want his properties to be shown.

Comment: I don't get your question.. you listen changes in the comboBox selection with an item listener... you get the person selected then what you want to do? Append to the textarea? You have to convert your `Person` class into a String representation, you can override `toString()` to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) to render the persons in combo box. You need to write an item listener to listen to selection change events on combo box. Based on the selection in the combo box, you can get the corresponding person and set the appropriate text to your text area.

For more information on JCombobox, visit this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

```
class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
       if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          Object item = event.getItem();
          // do something with object
          if(item instanceof Person) {
            this.selectedPerson = (Person) item;
            // textArea.setText(person.toString());
          } else {
            this.selectedPerson = null;
          }
       }
    }       
}
```

This 'ItemChangeListener' should be an inner class in your panel which contains both JComboBox and TextArea and the panel should also contain `selectedPerson` instance variable of type `Person`.

Comment: Yes but the problem is I can;t find how to get the info from that person when the person is selected. see my beginpost can u give me an example on how to find which object is selected in the combo box

Comment: Which value do I have to give to itemStateChanged?

Comment: You don't need to give any value to `itemStateChanged`. Just create an instance of `ItemChangeListener` and add this to your combo box using:
`comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener())`. When you change the value in combobox, the event handler calls `itemStateChanged` method and passes `ItemEvent` object.